# Convert genbank file into tbl file

Tags: python, phylogenetics, genbank

I want to submit some phage sequences to NCBI. So I want to transform a genbank file into a tbl file. Can someone help me please?
Thanks

Comment: Is tbl a Sequin file format equivalent ??  https://chlorobox.mpimp-golm.mpg.de/GenBank2Sequin.html

Comment: It's a perfectly valid question